# R Combine Excel files into a single Excel file with multiple sheets, where the sheets are sourced from different files but share the same structure

Tags: r, excel, loops, aggregate

I have 4 Excel files (a,b,c,d), each contains 6 Excel sheets.
All the files have the same structure (i.e., column names, sheet names).
I would like to have 1 final Excel Sheet with the aggregated data from the 4 files but divided in the different sheets.

I tried to aggregate it with a loop

```
for (excel_file in excel_files) 
{wb <- loadWorkbook(file.path(folder_path, excel_file))
sheet_name <- getSheetNames(excel_file)
for (sheet_name in getSheetNames(excel_file)) {
# Read data from the current sheet
sheet_data <- read.xlsx(excel_file, sheet = sheet_name)
addWorksheet(output_wb, sheet_name)
writeData(output_wb, sheet = sheet_name, x = sheet_data)} 
}
```